# Apache Spark is there a setting NOT to delete temp files on workers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to debug an issue with an import error for a Python file and custom package that I am submitting to a Spark cluster with spark-submit.

It would be really great to the structure of the temp file it's creating to temporarily hold the python code it's running but it always deletes the temp file.

So, is there a way to stop spark from deleting the temp folders that it deletes when I see

```
INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-144e34d1-bd37-4d99-8fae-e4c0e5df
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to put driver into sleep for some time:

```
import time, sys
sys.stdout.write("going to sleep\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(600) # 10 minutes
```

When you see `going to sleep` message in the driver logs, you have 10 minutes before context is killed and temp data are deleted.